# Cannot resolve aliases in Sitecore 5

Tags: iis-7, sitecore

We recently moved a website built using Sitecore 5 CMS to a new Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5 machine. But after this change, our Sitecore aliases no longer resolve.

**UPDATE** I don't think the problem has to do with our server move. There's something strange going on in the Sitecore API.

The problem is that this method call to Aliases.Exists() always returns false:

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Database.Aliases.Exists(args.LocalPath))
{
    var aliasId = Sitecore.Context.Database.Aliases.GetTargetID(args.LocalPath);        

    ...
}
```

But I can get the alias node using this code:

```
var folder = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items["/sitecore/system/Aliases"];
var aliasItem = folder.Axes.GetChild(args.LocalPath);
```

Where args.LocalPath is something like "/thisIsAnAlias".

We have AliasesActive turned on in the web.config file, and Anonymous users have read access to the Alias node.

Am I doing something wrong? Why won't the Context.Database.Aliases code find the alias?

Answer (score 0):

Probably already checked, but have you looked in System > Aliases folder to check that the aliases are still linked to their respective items? There is a field under 'Data' where you can confirm this called 'Linked item'.

Comment: Yes, the aliases I'm looking for have populated fields called "Linked item". The second code snippet, where I enumerate the children of the alias node, will find the alias that matches the supplied LocalPath, but the call to Exists() won't work.